# Hiding SharePoint 2013 Custom Actions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to hide a custom action in SharePoint using jQuery.   I can easily do this with the id of the custom action but I would like to avoid it because of possible changes to that long seemingly random id as SharePoint is upgraded.  Is there a selector based on the text that I assign to the action?

Tried searching but found nothing.  Tried creating the jQuery selector on my own but I am pretty much jQuery handicapped. :)

Here is the HTML produced by sharepoint for the buttom

```
<a class="ms-cui-ctl-large" id="{BFD14B83-563B-4C27-9BE8-C4F64D55D554}-Large" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" unselectable="on">
   <span class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer" unselectable="on">
          <span class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on">
              <img class="" style="" unselectable="on"  src="https://myserver/PUC/SiteAssets/images/Cancel.png" alt="Cancel"/>
      </span>
  </span>
  <span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">Cancel</span>
</a>
```

I guess what I want to do is select the anchor that has a span tag containing Cancel

Comment: which custom action are you talking about, can you please provide more details? is it List ribbon? is it siteactions?

Comment: Sorry yes, it would be the Display Form Ribbbon Custom Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

$( "a span:contains('Cancel')" ).parent().hide();

Example assumes you have a button that has the title of "Cancel".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!. suppose you have an action that titled by "Approve".

In SharePoint Designer, open related page at "Edit File in Advanced Mode"

Then put the following java script code, right after this:

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
           $("input[id*='Approve']").css("display","none");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have seen this code before but my button is called Cancel Request and I am not seeing Cancel Request anywhere in the button's ID.   It seems to be dort of a GUID serial number BFD14B83-563B-4C27-9BE8-C4F64D55D554}-Large.  This is a Display Form Ribbbon Custom Action.

Comment: Unless you give how the generated html structure looks like, it will be difficult to give solution. Do you have something like this? <span id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-0" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">  and within this you have anchor tag. If yes than you can add simple css #Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-0{display:none;}

Comment: Updated my orginal post with html that sharepoint is creating